# How to run a command and don't wait for application exit?

Tags: c, linux, process

I need to run a command,but that don't lock my application until exit of it,like do `system()` function.

Comment: Note that if the parent process exits it will send a SIGHUP to the child.  Assuming that you want the child to continue running, the child should ignore SIGHUP by using signal handling, or run the program using nohup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `fork()` to create a new process, and `exec*()` to replace it with a new application.

Answer (score 2):

```
pid_t pid;

if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    ...fork failed...
else if (pid == 0)
{
     ...create command line in array of char pointers argv...
     ...sort out I/O -- redirect stdin from /dev/null?...
     execvp(argv[0], argv);
     ...report exec failed on stderr...
     _exit(126);
}
...parent process...gets on with life...
```